# In how many ways can we select $x$ distinct candies from a collection of $n$ candies of distinct types?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Suppose we have k distinct types of jars.

Lets name these jars as ***jar1 , jar2 , jar3....jark***

Now each jar have some candies. A jar will have same type of candies.

Moreover no two jars have same type of candies.

Thus we have $p_1$ candies in jar1, $p_2$ candies in jar2......$p_k$ candies in jark.

A total of $n$ candies are there.

Hence: $${p_1+p_2+.....+p_k=n}$$

Now all these candies from all jars are emptied on a sheet of paper.

We need to select $x$ **distinct** candies from these $n$ candies where $x<k$

How many ways are there for doing so?

Comment: How is this "really spooky"?

Comment: @MGA Cause jars and candies and Halloween

Comment: Note you can ask for $x\le k$ instead of just $x<k$. Also, have you had any thoughts/ made any progress on this problem so far? It's good to tell users such things so they can help you where you are stuck.

Comment: I assume the candies from each jar are identical between each other and candies from different jars are distinct, is this assumption correct?

Comment: @dREaM "A jar will have same type of candies.

Moreover no two jars have same type of candies."

Comment: Please make titles informative and a bit less subjective.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to use generating functions. Use $z$ to count candies, then the candies from jar $i$ are represented by:

$\begin{align}
1 + z + \dotsb + z^{p_i}
  = \frac{1 - z^{p_i + 1}}{1 - z}
\end{align}$

The full collection of candies is:

$\begin{align}
\prod_{1 \le i \le k} \frac{1 - z^{p_i + 1}}{1 - z}
\end{align}$

and you want the number of ways to make up $x$ candies, the coefficient of $z^x$:

$\begin{align}
[z^x] \prod_{1 \le i \le k} \frac{1 - z^{p_i + 1}}{1 - z}
\end{align}$

Sorry, but unless some other conditions are imposed (e.g. $x \le p_i$ for all $i$, or even all $p_i$ the same), there is no simple expression for what you are asking for.

Comment: Lets use 3 jars with 2,1 and 1 candies respectively.If we want to select 2 distinct candies,answer should have been 5 but by your explanation it is coming 4.

Comment: @NamanAgarwal It is really not clear what **distinct** candies means then. Maybe you should give an example. If the first jar has candies a1 and a2, the second one has candy b1 and the third one has candy c1, which of those candies are considered distinct?